# Get camera resolutions android

Tags: android, video, camera, resolution

Im trying to recieve a list of supported camera video resolutions but im out of options...

getSupportedPictureSize() returns values for photos,

getSupportedPreviewSize() crashes whole phone because im recording without preview

getSupportedVideoSize() return null...

Is there any other method to get info about supported resolutions?

Comment: found workaroud: just use CamcorderProfile.hasProfile(int what_profile)

Answer (score 1):

The standard camera APIs may not totally work on different devices. So usually I'll print out all relevant parameters to check what I can use. You can use the following code:

```
        Camera camera = Camera.open();
        Parameters param = camera.getParameters();
        Log.i("camera", "parameters: " + param.flatten());
```

The log I got from my device:

> 02-13 15:10:36.185: I/camera(19544): parameters:
>   preferred-preview-size-for-video=1280x720;zoom=0;max-num-detected-faces-hw=5;zoom-supported=true;metering=center;contrast=2;whitebalance=auto;scene-mode=auto;jpeg-quality=100;preview-format-values=yuv420sp,yuv420p;jpeg-thumbnail-quality=100;preview-format=yuv420sp;video-size-values=1280x720,1920x1080,960x720,720x480,640x480,352x288,320x240,176x144;preview-size=960x720;focal-length=3.700000;iso=auto;fast-fps-mode=0;flash-mode-values=auto,off,on,torch;preview-frame-rate-values=30,20,15,10;preview-frame-rate=30;focus-mode-values=auto,infinity,macro,fixed,continuous-picture,continuous-video;jpeg-thumbnail-width=160;video-size=1280x720;scene-mode-values=auto,portrait,landscape,night,beach,snow,sunset,fireworks,sports,party,candlelight,dusk-dawn,fall-color,text,back-light;preview-fps-range-values=(10000,10000),(15000,15000),(15000,30000),(30000,30000);jpeg-thumbnail-size-values=160x120,160x90,144x96,0x0;zoom-ratios=100,102,104,109,111,113,119,121,124,131,134,138,146,150,155,159,165,170,182,189,200,213,222,232,243,255,283,300,319,364,400;preview-size-values=960x720,1280x720,640x480,352x288,320x240;picture-size-values=640x480,960x720,1024x768,1280x720,1600x1200,2560x1920,3264x2448,2048x1536,3264x1836,2048x1152,3264x2176;preview-fps-range=15000,30000;min-exposure-compensation=-4;antibanding=off;max-num-focus-areas=1;vertical-view-angle=49.3;horizontal-view-angle=63;video-stabilization-supported=true;jpeg-thumbnail-height=120;smooth-zoom-supported=false;focus-mode=auto;auto-whitebalance-lock-supported=true;video-frame-format=yuv420sp;picture-format-values=jpeg;max-exposure-compensation=4;focus-areas=(0,0,0,0,0);exposure-compensation=0;exposure-compensation-step=0.5;flash-mode=off;effect-values=none,mono,negative,sepia,solarize,posterize,washed,vintage-warm,vintage-cold,point-blue,point-red-yellow,point-green,cartoonize;picture-size=640x480;max-zoom=30;effect=none;whitebalance-values=auto,incandescent,fluorescent,daylight,cloudy-daylight;picture-format=jpeg;focus-distances=0.15,1.20,Infinity;auto-exposure-lock-supported=true;antibanding-values=50hz,off